Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysql_native_password.so: cannot open shared object file
I am try to execute genomepy to install biological genome data but the software is raising an exception related to a mysql client as shown below.
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysql_native_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am running Debian 12 OS.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm


I have installed mysql-client using the command below.
apt-get install default-mysql-client

When I execute the command below.
genomepy install xenTro9 --UCSC-annotation refGene

I get the output below.
(base) root@567b7019ab11:/local/data/nf_genome_annot_backend# date;time genomepy install xenTro9 --UCSC-annotation refGene;date;
Sun Dec 22 08:32:37 UTC 2024
08:32:41 | INFO | Downloading the refGene annotation from the UCSC MySQL database.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 327, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysql_native_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/genomepy/providers/ucsc.py", line 343, in download_annotation
    download_annotation(name, annot, genomes_dir, localname)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/genomepy/providers/ucsc.py", line 560, in download_annotation
    cols = list(query_ucsc(command, database=name))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


You could try this as it should have the required plugins
sudo apt-get install mysql-server 

Find the directory where MySQL plugins are stored....typically /usr/lib/mysql/plugin OR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19.0/plugin/
Verify the plugin file, check if the mysql_native_password.so file exists in the plugin directory. If it doesn't, reinstall the MySQL server.
see that the MySQL connector for python is correctly configured to use the native password plugin.
Add the following line to your MySQL config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

after making changes to the configuration, restart the MySQL server: sudo service mysql restart
Reinstall the MySQL connector for Python
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector-python

Then try the genomepy install command again..
